# Blazor custom _Layout.cshtml - Can you use two?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

When I create a Blazor server project, _Host.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml files are created.

The _Host.cshtml file contains the following:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

From what I've read you're supposed to be able to drop a _Layout.cshtml in a nested folder along with the calling page and it should use that _Layout.cshtml or look in the parent directory if not found.

My issue is that I can't get this to work. With a freshly created project I've created a 'Test' subfolder under 'Pages', copied the Counter.razor and _Layout.cshtml, change the `@page` path to `/test/counter` and make a cosmetic change to the _Layout.cshtml but the layout still defaults to the one in the parent Pages folder.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are mixed two technologies here.  _layout files are used in Razor server side rendering.  `Counter.razor` is a Blazor page/route.  Do you want to change the layout of the Blazor application.  _Layout in a Blazor application just provides the shell page, loading the CSS and JS stuff.  The Blazor Layout changes the UI.  What "cosmetic" change are you making?  What are you trying to achieve?  Are you trying to run multiple Blazor Applications?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis What I'm trying to achieve is essentially a separate Blazor app that you can incorporate into another Blazor app. So imagine creating a vanilla Blazor app, referencing an RCL project that has a bespoke area/path so that when you go "/any-page" you're in the vanilla Blazor app but when you go "/rcl/any-age" you are in a custom part of the application with its own layout including base html/head/body and css/js references. Essentially a kind of shadow app that comes from the RCL project.

Comment: This article - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5287009/Blazor-Hydra-Hosting-Multiple-Blazor-SPAs-on-a-sin -  explains how to host multiple Server and WASM sites within the same .NetCore web application.  I'm not sure how closely it fits with your requirement, but it will point you in the right direction.   The repo is now here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Hydra